# Using wp_mail() function outside of WordPress and through PHP CLI

Tags: wp-mail

I am developing a simple PHP script that will send emails to users.
The script is located outside of WP directory and its run through a cronjob.
Example cron job call:

```
php /PATH/TO/SCIRPT/script.php >> /PATH/TO/SCIRPT/history.log
```

and here’s part of the code:

```
<?php

require_once "/PATH/TO/WP/wp-load.php";

$res = wp_mail('email', 'title', 'body');
```

When I use PHP CLI to run the script `$res` is always false. But if I run the same script from the web it works just fine.

Below are the server details:
ubuntu 16.04lts up-to-date with php 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: not sure your server config, if you're on a lamp stack php-cli uses a different php.ini for `apache2` or `fpm`, and `cli` perhaps verify email settings are right in `/etc/php/7.x/cli/php.ini`

Comment: Dev server is running Ubuntu 16.04LTS (vagrant box).  The production server has the exact same setup. I will check cli php.ini settings right now.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using wp_mail rather than then PHP mail function?

Comment: @RickHellewell Yes. I am using WordPress SMTP plugin to send emails using my Mailgun account. Using wp_mail() I will be able to send emails without entire PHP library (PHPMailer) just for 20 lines of code.